# different folders in a partition as mount points?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

i want to have 2 partitions. one is called system. the other is private.

in the private partition i've got some folders i want to mount into system as system folders.

folders in private:
- www
- home

mount points in system:
- /var/www
- /home

is this possible? cause it seems that you can only specify a whole partition to use for a mount point and not a folder in a partition or am i wrong?

i run ubuntu server.

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, you can do this with bind mounts.

These commands:

```
mount --bind /private/www /var/www
mount --bind /private/home /home
```

Will do what you want. The fstab version of them is:

```
/private/www   /var/www  none  bind
/private/home  /home     none  bind
```

Comment: ...the unspoken assumption being that you've previously mounted the private partition to */private* ...right?

Comment: so i dont have to do this during installation? but what happens to the files in /var/www if i mount /private/www there instead? so goes with /home. cause maybe someone already created some users in /home.

Comment: The files are still there, just hidden by the filesystem that is mounted on top. If you need access to them, consider adding links in, for example, /home to the directories in /private/home

Comment: Yes same caveats of normal mounting still apply, the src has to exist (you can't mount /dev/md0 to / if you don't have /dev/md0), contents of the dst directory will be hidden. Did I answer you question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount the whole volume somewhere so that you can get access to the contents. Once you have done that you can do a **bind mount** to mount part of it somewhere else as well. See [the `mount(8)` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) for details:

> **Bind mount operation**
>
> Remount part of the file hierarchy somewhere else.  The call is:
>
> ```
>     mount --bind olddir newdir
> ```
>
> or by using this fstab entry:
>
> ```
>     /olddir /newdir none bind
> ```
>
> After this call the same contents are accessible in two places.
>
> It is important to understand that "bind" does not create any
> second-class or special node in the kernel VFS. The "bind" is just
> another operation to attach a filesystem. There is nowhere stored
> information that the filesystem has been attached by a "bind"
> operation. The olddir and newdir are independent and the olddir may be
> unmounted.